# TS140 Lenovo ThinkServer i3-4150 CPU upgrade LGA 1150 i3-4150 to e3-1276v3 or e3-1226v3?

Tags: server, processor, web-server

I have TS140 server running Ubuntu and several vm's for apps, web, MySQL.  Looking to upgrade CPU from stock i3-4150.   It is LGA 1150 (H3) socket.  I have the newer motherboard.

Is e3-1230v3, e3-1226v3, e3-1240v3 or e3-1276v3 better suited for server and if so, are there significant differences?

If I upgrade to e3-1240v3 (doesn't have gpu) will I still be able to run ubuntu desktop in the vm's ?

Is there a broadwell that would work in the LGA 1150 (H3)?  e3-1285v4?

Looking to spend ~ $300

Answer (score 1):

The e3-1276v3 processor is significantly faster.  Here is link to openbenchmark of the i3-4150v3 and e3-1276v3 processors running pts/multicore benchmark http://openbenchmarking.org/result/1707040-KH-1707042KH29